# Macro parameter character in \input file

Tags: macros

I would like to include some paragraphs from external .tex files in my document, very similar to what `\lipsum` does. As far as I understood it until now is using `\input` equivalent to directly typing text and commands.

However, when running the MWE below

```
\begin{filecontents}{myTextFile.tex}
\ifthenelse{#2=1}{first paragraph}{}
\ifthenelse{#2=2}{second paragraph}{}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\myParagraphs[2]{\input{#1}}

\begin{document}
\myParagraphs{myTextFile.tex}{2}
\end{document}
```

I get the error message

> You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.

Thus, '#2' is not known in *myTextFile.tex*. How can I make #2 known there, or is there an easier way to define `\myParagraphs{<file>}{<paragraph no>}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do like that. The definition of `\myParagraphs` doesn't use `#2`; so

```
\myParagraphs{myTextFile.tex}{2}
```

becomes

```
\input{myTextFile}
```

and so TeX reads your file, where `#2` is illegal. Here's a way: define a temporary macro to expand to the value of `#2`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myTextFile.tex}
\ifthenelse{\second=1}{first paragraph}{}
\ifthenelse{\second=2}{second paragraph}{}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\myParagraphs[2]{\def\second{#2}\input{#1}}

\begin{document}
\myParagraphs{myTextFile.tex}{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot collect stuff that way. You need to store each paragraph in a macro with a name that can then be chosen via an option. That is how `lipsum` etc. works.

It might be an idea to use `etoolbox` and its `\csdef` macro to build the macros and `\csuse` to execute them.